# Array to string conversion ErrorException while uploading image in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I use 3 arrays to store in table courses. Please help me to save array in string or save array in database...my problem with array:

- I can't store and save image in database
- I can't save array outcomes and requirements in  database

```html
<div class="col-md-10"><input type="file" class="form-control" name="images" id="images" ></div>
    //and this 
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="outcomes[]" id="outcomes">
    //or this
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="requirements[]" id="requirements">
```

My store function call:

```
public function store(CourseRequest $request)
{
    $imageUrl = $this->upload2Images($request->file('images'));

    auth()->user()->course()->create( 
        $request->except(['_token','files']),
        ['images'=>$imageUrl]);

    return redirect(route('courses.index'));
}
```

and `upload2Images()` is

```
public function upload2Images($file)
    {
        $year = Carbon::now()->year;
        $month = Carbon::now()->month;
        $imagePath = "upload/images/{$year}/{$month}/";
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file = $file->move(public_path($imagePath), $filename);
        $url['images'] = "upload/images/{$year}/{$month}/$filename";
        return $url;
    }
```

When I use

```
$data = array_merge(
            $request->except(['_token','files','outcomes','requirements']),
            $images
        );
$id =  auth()->user()->course()->create($data)->id;
```

It works fine but outcomes and requirements is array that I hide this way.
Can I pass this arguments?

Answer (score 2):

You're calling:

```
    $url['images'] = "upload/images/{$year}/{$month}/$filename";
    return $url;
```

Then:

```
    $imageUrl = $this->upload2Images($request->file('images'));
```

So `$imageUrl` is an array. but the code to save the record expects that to be a string.

```
`...->create( $request->except(['_token','files']),['images'=>$imageUrl]);`
```

Also, you seem to be passing 2 parameters to `create` when it only takes one

Maybe you meant to call something like the below?

```
$images = $this->upload2Images($request->file('images'));
$data = array_merge($request->except(['_token','files']), $images);
auth()->user()->course()->create($data);
```

Comment: i use array_merge  befor say you. but not work....i use this $data = array_merge($request->except(['_token','files','outcomes','requirements']), $images); and work ...

Comment: outcomes and requirements is array that i hide this way.
can i pass this arrguments?

@Wesley Smith

Comment: @tohid Im not sure I follow this bit "outcomes and requirements is array that i hide this way. can i pass this arrgument", can  you maybe re-phrase that?

Comment: thank you bro ...i say outcomes and requirements stored array and when i insert in except(['_token','requirements ','outcomes ']) ..it is work...and for solve this problem i insert in model protected $casts = [
        'images' => 'array',
        'requirements' => 'array',
        'outcomes' => 'array',
    ];

Answer (score 1):

solved thanks
i use in model of this

```
protected $casts = [
        'images' => 'array',
        'requirements' => 'array',
        'outcomes' => 'array',
    ];
```

and controller use this

```
   $images = $this->upload2Images($request->file('images'));
        $requirements = $request->requirements;
        $outcomes = $request->outcomes;

        $data = array_merge($request->except(['_token']), ['images'=>$images],['requirements'=>$requirements],['outcomes'=>$outcomes]);
        $id =  auth()->user()->course()->create($data)->id;
```